# How to space first_name + last_name C++

Tags: class, codeblocks, spacing

My question is how can i use spaces between first_name and last_name after i instruct the user to input his name. 
I am using code blocks and I'm kinda confused. 
In Dev C++ i can do

```
   cout<<first_name<<" "<<last_name;
```

Now what I am doing is just practicing C++ using variables in a class. 
Here is my code.

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<string>
    using namespace std;

    class DanielClass
      {
     public:
        int setNameFunction(string first_name, string last_name)
        {
    cout<<"Enter your first name here: ";
    cin>>first_name;
    cout<<"Enter your last name here: ";
    cin>>last_name;
    name = first_name + last_name;
        }

        string getNameFunction()
        {

    return name;
        }

    private:
       string name;
    };


    int main()
    {

       DanielClass NameObject;
       NameObject.setNameFunction("", "");
       cout<<NameObject.getNameFunction();

       cout<<"\n\n";
       return 0;
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add string literals (which is just a term for a string entered directly into the code with quotes around it -- like the " " in the second line of code below) to string variables using the '+' operator.

You just need to change the line that reads:

```
    name = first_name + last_name;
```

to:

```
    name = first_name + " " + last_name;
```

Comment: Wow Sir Barry Gackle, Really Thank you!